# How to simplify Or(Not(y), And(y, Not(x))) to Or(Not(y), Not(x)) with Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I tried to use Z3 to simplify `~y or (y, ~x)` to `~y or ~x`, but can't seem to do so, even when I use the tactic `ctx-solver-simplify`. Below is the Python code demonstrating what I have done.  Any idea on how to achieve this?  Thanks,

```
sage: x,y = z3.Bools('x y')
sage: f = Or(Not(y), And(y, Not(x)))
sage: simpl = Tactic('ctx-solver-simplify')
sage: simpl = z3.TryFor(simpl, 300000)
sage: simpl(f).as_expr()
Or(Not(y), And(y, Not(x)))   # cannot simplify
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot expect z3 to perform such simplifications as what you consider "simple" and what it considers "simple" can differ vastly.

Having said that, you can run `help_simplify()` and it'll show you all the options `simplify` supports. From what I can see, there isn't a rule in there that'll help with your case.

Note that SMT solvers are not really designed for this sort of "user-level" simplification. A more traditional thing to do would be to ask z3 if what you consider a simplified form is indeed equivalent. In your case, something like:

```py
from z3 import *

x, y = Bools('x y')

f = Or(Not(y), And(y, Not(x)))
g = Or(Not(y), Not(x))

prove(f == g)
```

To which z3 responds:

```
proved
```

Answer (score 1):

Z3 has a strong machinery to find solutions, but all that is under the hood.

[Sympy](https://www.sympy.org), Python's symbolic math library is more suited for [this kind](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html) of simplifications. `srepr()` can be used to show the internal format. Default the boolean operators are shown as `&`, `|` and `~`. You also can directly use these symbols to write expressions.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Or, Not, And, srepr

x, y = symbols('x y')
f = Or(Not(y), And(y, Not(x))) # or f = ~y | (y & ~x)

print(f) # ~y | (y & ~x)
print(f.simplify()) # ~x | ~y
print(srepr(f)) # Or(Not(Symbol('y')), And(Symbol('y'), Not(Symbol('x'))))
print(srepr(f.simplify())) # Or(Not(Symbol('x')), Not(Symbol('y')))
```