# How to measure size of formula in Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am working in Z3 with extremely large formulae, so there is no way I can analyze them (indeed, printing them is hard). Thus, I would like to perform some high-level analysis using tools that Z3 may have.

Concretely, consider I have a formula `phi` and I perform `simplify(phi)`. Is there any way I can measure the size of both formulae? Of course, there are different notions of size, but is there anyone built-in? I basically want to know if the application of `simplify(phi)` has modified the formula (since I am aware that using `simplify(phi)` does not guarantee anything [1,2]).

[1] [How to simplify Or(Not(y), And(y, Not(x))) to Or(Not(y), Not(x)) with Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792685/how-to-simplify-ornoty-andy-notx-to-ornoty-notx-with-z3)
[2] [Simplification with Z3 does not simplify as much as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77417006/simplification-with-z3-does-not-simplify-as-much-as-expected)

Comment: I'm not aware of any default metrics available. You can treat the formula as a tree, and count number of nodes, width, depth; calculate the max breadth any level, or any combination thereof. The question is whether if any of these metrics will be useful. The only way to find out is to try, as I think the answer will be application specific. (There's some skeleton code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966273/936310, which you can start with to traverse the formula.)

Comment: Looks like there is no standard method, then. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probes might be what you are searching for.

Probes allow for checking various measures related to a goal in Z3, and many different types of measures over the goals are implemented. [1]

Assuming you are interfacing to Z3 through the Python API, you can obtain a list of available probes through the command:

```
describe_probes()
```

Here is an example of usage of probes in Z3py:

```
from z3 import *

probe = Probe('num-exprs')

A, B = Bools('A B')
phi = Or(And(A, B), And(A, B))
phi_simple = simplify(phi)

print(probe(phi))
print(probe(phi_simple))
```

[1] https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/docs/strategies/probes/

Comment: This is an interesting idea. However, the documentation suggests probes apply to goals, not to expressions. I’m not sure what actually happens when you use it like you did above. Perhaps it does the right thing? And again, whether this solves the original question is open. But definitely worth exploring. Great find!

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for the response. On your example, it seems to work (result is `4` in `phi`, whereas `2` in `phi_simple`), however I tested it with some other examples and I receive very strange results: sometimes, the simplified one is larger than the original one. I cannot show an instance of this now, but I can tell you that I tried with another probe (`'memory'`) and is exactly the same in both the original and the simplified one. Do you have any clue why this is happening? Thanks again!

Comment: A goal is a conjunction of assertions. Looking inside the [source code of Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master), I found the file `src/tactic/probe.cpp` which explains how probes work internally. 

'memory' probe seems to return the allocated memory by z3 independently from the goal, so I guess that's why it's the same in both cases. 

Probe 'size' seems to return the number of formulas composing a goal.

Probe 'num-exprs' seems to return the associated number of expressions of a specific goal and it seems that it does a recursive count on each formula composing the goal

Comment: Thank you very much! Then, do you have any idea of a why a simplified phi would have a larger number of 'num-exprs' than the original one?

Comment: I think the difference lies in how a goal is constructed. Let's take as an example the formula `A and B and C`, with A,B,C as boolean variables: we would have `size = 3`, since the goal is the conjunction of the 3 variables, and `num-exprs = 3` since each subformula of the goal is of size 1 (only the variable). In `A or B or C`, we would have a `size = 1` since is the conjunction of only one formula, and `num-exprs = 5` since it counts 2 expressions for the operators and 3 for the variables. How the 'num-exprs' for each formula in a goal is counted is in file `src/ast/for_each_expr.cpp#L23`

Comment: Hm... I can understand that `size=1` in one case and `size=3` in the other one (because of the goal), but should not `num-exprs` be the same in both cases? I mean, in both cases we have `2` expressions for operators (`and` and `or`) and `3` for the variables... or is it the case that `and` is not considered as operator because it rather is a "conjunction of/for goals"? Thanks again

Comment: That is exactly the case, since `and` is a conjunction of goals, the three goals will be respectively `A`, `B` and `C`, now we count the expressions of the three goals separately and sum them up, but since there are only variables the sum will be 1 + 1 + 1 = 3. That is why the `and` operator is not considered in the count in this case.